# unity freezes due to use of system.IO.ports.serialport

Tags: c#, serial-port, unity-game-engine

I am using a c# script to send things over serial. Everything works out fine. The other end is getting all the right data. Problem is, it only works for about 110 to 30 seconds, then unity freezes. I know that this is better suited for the unity forums, but i dont seem to get any replies there, so i have come here.

code below:

```
 using UnityEngine;
 using System.Collections;
 using System.IO.Ports;

 public class NewBehaviourScript : MonoBehaviour {
byte[] StepperAngle = new byte[1];
short servoAngle = 0;
byte[] servoArray = new byte[2];

SerialPort sp = new SerialPort("COM4", 9600);
// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    sp.Open();
    sp.ReadTimeout = 1;
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {
    StepperAngle[0] = (byte)(transform.localEulerAngles.y * 50/360);
    servoAngle = (short)(transform.localEulerAngles.z* 10e8); // turn fl2oat      into short. short is split right down center
    servoArray[0] = (byte)(servoAngle/10e8);
    servoArray[1] = (byte)(servoAngle % 10e8);
    sp.Write(StepperAngle,0,1); 
    //try{
        //print(StepperAngle[0]);
    //}catch(System.Exception){
        //print("stupid  " + stepperAngle);
    //}
  }
 }
```

and also, the culprit IS the line sp.Write(StepperAngle[0]); When commented out everything goes fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yaay. It seems that the issue was not in fact the sp.Write(); call but in fact was the input buffer overflowing. It seems that the arduino code was writing and the unity code was not reading. This caused Unity to freeze up. How removing sp.Write(StepperAngle,0,1); fixed it I have no idea.